# org mode TAB doesn't unfold headings

Tags: org-mode, doom

I have the strangest problem - ever since reinstalling Doom I can only fold org headings
but then they're stuck folded.. TAB doen't do anything, although I did check and it's still bound to org-cycle...
S-TAB doen't work either.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Please, state the version of Doom you are using. Can you report the value of `org-tab-first-hook` from `describe-variable`? Does this happen with and without your personal config file? Also, generally, when I have problems with Doom, I try to reinstall it from fresh, by completely removing all related folders, of course, after backing them up.

Comment: Thanks! 
This is a link to the output of `doom/info`: https://pastebin.com/Uq9gKw07  (I'm on doom 3.0).
This is the value of `org-tab-first-hook`
`(+org-yas-expand-maybe-h +org-indent-maybe-h org-babel-hide-result-toggle-maybe org-babel-header-arg-expand +org-clear-babel-results-h +org-cycle-only-current-subtree-h)`

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you launch Doom without your personal configuration file?

Comment: No, with an empty config file it works as expected

Comment: a possible hint is that I get "SUBTREE (NO CHILDREN)" when I hit `TAB` on the folded header. There is an elispes at the end of the header.

Comment: You have to find the piece of code that breaks the intended behaviour either using a binary search by commenting out parts of your init file and completely restarting Doom, not just by reloading it; or just commenting out pieces of your init file that configures the org mode.

Comment: I am not using doom but sometimes I have the same problem. I can resolve it by killing the buffer and finding the file again. However, I have no clue why this (inconsistently) happens.

Comment: @JonathanSahar, did you ever solve this? I have a large org-mode file in which this happens, but have not been able to find the issue. What fjesser suggests in the latest comment works for me, but that's not very satisfying as a solution. :-)

Comment: Same with me: it happens in all my large org files. Restarting emacs temporarily solves the issue though.

Comment: I have a similar problem: In my big org files (>3 MB) sometimes some of the heading doesn't unfold. My files start with alle headings folded. I can unfold the heading, if I isearch some term from the folded text.
When examining the ellipsis of the folded heading that could not be unfolded, there is an overlay, all ellipses of unfoldable headings have the new org-fold text properties.
Reloading the file does not help, but closing an reopening does -- but not everytime for all entries.
Any idea what I could examine further? What does isearch do differently than org-cicle?